# Laravel unit testing. Failed asserting that false is true

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

Im trying to test my reset password functionality but im getting the error. Can someone help me? Where am i wrong? Thanks.

```
    public function test_it_reset_password_with_valid_token()
{
    // Given
    Event::fake();
    $user = Customer::factory()->create();

    // When
    $response = $this->post('/password/reset', [
        'token' => $this->getValidToken($user),
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => 'new-password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'new-password',
    ]);

    // Then
    $this->assertEquals($user->email, $user->fresh()->email);
    $this->assertTrue(Hash::check('new-password', $user->fresh()->password));
    $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);

    Event::assertDispatched(PasswordReset::class);
}
```

[image: Here is error message]

Comment: donc post images of code, post the code/text itself.

Comment: dump the response of your post call to see if there are any errors.

Comment: You should assert that the response is a 200 before asserting the rest.

Comment: Expected response status code [200] but received 302.
  
  The following errors occurred during the request:
  
  This password reset token is invalid.
  
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 302. i got error like this when i assert response 200